# Unable to find the reason why a folder is ignored in Git

Tags: git

I have a repo where I have a folder called **web/folder** that is being ignored by Git. At one point, I wanted this folder to be ignored and added it using .gitignore file. But now, even if I delete the .gitignore file, it continues to exclude the `web/folder`. I tried `git status --ignored` and I can see that the folder is ignored. I don't know why though (especially since .gitignore no longer exists)! Is there a way I can force git to include this folder again?

`NOTE:` I found that if I run `git add web/folder -f` it would add the files forcibly. However, I am curious to know why `web/folder` is ignored to begin with.

```
git status --ignored
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.    
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .DS_Store
        .idea/
        web/folder/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: There are multiple places where Git looks for ignore rules. A `.gitignore` file can be placed in every project directory (and has effect only in that directory and its subdirectories). Make sure there ignored directory is not listed in `web/.gitignore`. Then check the content of file `.git/info/exclude`. This is a local, project-specific ignore file. Also, check the output of `git config --global --get core.excludesFile` to find out the location of the local account-wide ignore file, maybe the directory is listed there.

Comment: Thank you so much @axiac. Please post this as an answer so I could accept it. I used `git config --global --get core.excludesFile` as you recommended and found the folder listed there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
git check-ignore -v web/folder/
```

to see why the folder is ignored. The `-v` flag should show you the reason e.g.

```
.git/info/exclude:42:web/f*   web/folder/
```

means that on line 42 of the file .git/info/exclude, the pattern `web/f*` matches the path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped :)